# SQLAlchemy MSSQL Bulk Inserts, Issue with Efficiency

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, bulkinsert

I need to insert 36 million rows from Oracle to MSSQL. The below code works but even with chunking at 1k (since you can only insert 1k rows at a time in MSSQL) it is not quick at all. Current estimates have this taking around 100 hours which won't cut it :)

```
def method(self):

    # get IDs and Dates from Oracle
    ids_and_dates = self.get_ids_and_dates()

    # get 2 each time
    for chunk in chunks(ids_and_dates, 2):
        # set up list for storing each where clause
        where_clauses = []
        for id, last_change_dt in chunk:
            where_clauses.append(self.queries['where'] % {dict})

        # set up final SELECT statement
        details_query = self.queries['details'] % " OR ".join([wc for wc in where_clauses])

        details_rows = [str(r).replace("None", "null") for r in self.src_adapter.fetchall(details_query)]

        for tup in chunks(details_rows, 1000): 
            # tup in the form of ["(VALUES_QUERY)"], remove []""
            insert_query = self.queries['insert'] % ', '.join(c for c in tup if c not in '[]{}""')
            self.dest_adapter.execute(insert_query)
```

I realize `fetchall` isn't ideal from what I've been reading. Should I consider implementing something else? And should I try out `executemany` instead of using `execute` for the inserts?

The Oracle query standalone was really slow so I broke it up into a few queries:

1. query1 gets IDs and dates.
2. query 2 uses the IDs and dates from query1 and selects more columns (chunked at max 2 OR statements).
3. query3 takes the query2 data and inserts that into MSSQL.

Comment: You should provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Thinking only of code, executemany will be more effective than execute because you insert several rows. But your problem seems first dependent of hardware and configurations of Orable and MySQL servers. You should timed/profiled your code to understand what part cost the most, and then try to figure out which part consume the most time.

Comment: so the issue is Oracle, not SQL then?

Comment: @Greg correct, the chunk 1k insert piece seems fine when it actually gets in that `for` loop, but the real bottleneck seems to be with `fetchall(details_query)`

Comment: I suggest fixing your tags then, since it's not a sql issue

Comment: which driver do you use? pymssql vs pyodbc? And if you don't mind much about using sqlalchemy I recommend the ctds (https://zillow.github.io/ctds/bulk_insert.html) library to handle large inserts like this.